# > Task :shared:podBuildFirebaseCoreIphonesimulator FAILED

Tags: firebase, cocoapods, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to integrate Firebase into my KMM application using the expect/actual framework. The Android class uses Android's Firebase (which is just imported from the `androidMain` source set), and the iOS class uses cocoapods. The android side works perfectly and is able to get the required dependencies from androidMain, but the ios is not able to recognize it's cocoapods. I installed the `FirebaseCore` and `FirebaseFirestore` pods and created a cocoapods module in my `build.gradle.kts` file. I'm getting the following error:

```
> Task :shared:podBuildFirebaseCoreIphonesimulator FAILED
error: Executing of 'xcodebuild -project Pods.xcodeproj -scheme FirebaseCore -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration Release' failed with code 65 and message:
```

Here is my `build.gradle.kts` file:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
    kotlin("native.cocoapods")
}

@OptIn(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi::class)
kotlin {
    targetHierarchy.default()

    android {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "1.8"
            }
        }
    }
    
    iosX64()
    iosArm64()
    iosSimulatorArm64()

    cocoapods {
        summary = "Some description for the Shared Module"
        homepage = "Link to the Shared Module homepage"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "14.1"
        version = "1.0"

        pod("FirebaseCore")
        pod("FirebaseFirestore")

        framework {
            baseName = "shared"
        }
    }

        sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
//                implementation("dev.gitlive:firebase-firestore:1.10.0")
//                implementation("dev.gitlive:firebase-common:1.10.0")
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }

        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                // firebase
                implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.3.1"))
                implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx")
                implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx")
            }
        }
        val androidUnitTest by getting {
            dependencies {
            }
        }

        val iosMain by getting {
            dependencies {
            }
        }
        val iosTest by getting {
            dependencies {
            }
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.cardgameapp"
    compileSdk = 33
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 33
    }
}
```

My `.podspec`:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
    spec.name                     = 'shared'
    spec.version                  = '1.0'
    spec.homepage                 = 'Link to the Shared Module homepage'
    spec.source                   = { :http=> ''}
    spec.authors                  = ''
    spec.license                  = ''
    spec.summary                  = 'Some description for the Shared Module'
    spec.vendored_frameworks      = 'build/cocoapods/framework/shared.framework'
    spec.libraries                = 'c++'
    spec.ios.deployment_target = '14.1'
    spec.dependency 'FirebaseCore'
    spec.dependency 'FirebaseFirestore'
                
    spec.pod_target_xcconfig = {
        'KOTLIN_PROJECT_PATH' => ':shared',
        'PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME' => 'shared',
    }
                
    spec.script_phases = [
        {
            :name => 'Build shared',
            :execution_position => :before_compile,
            :shell_path => '/bin/sh',
            :script => <<-SCRIPT
                if [ "YES" = "$OVERRIDE_KOTLIN_BUILD_IDE_SUPPORTED" ]; then
                  echo "Skipping Gradle build task invocation due to OVERRIDE_KOTLIN_BUILD_IDE_SUPPORTED environment variable set to \"YES\""
                  exit 0
                fi
                set -ev
                REPO_ROOT="$PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT"
                "$REPO_ROOT/../gradlew" -p "$REPO_ROOT" $KOTLIN_PROJECT_PATH:syncFramework \
                    -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.platform=$PLATFORM_NAME \
                    -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.archs="$ARCHS" \
                    -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.configuration="$CONFIGURATION"
            SCRIPT
        }
    ]
                
end
```

And my `Podfile`:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '14.1'

target 'Cards' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Cards
  pod 'FirebaseCore'
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore'

end
```

I have CocoaPods 1.13.0 and ruby 3.2.2 installed on my Macbook Pro M2 Pro.

Sorry for the overload of information, I've been stuck on this issue for the past 3 days and am losing my mind haha. Thank you in advance for any support!

I have tried to install three different versions of ruby, pod installed and deintegrated numerous times, invalidated so many caches and cleaned so many builds. I have manually created a gradle wrapper for `version 8.0`.